# C# Referencing a dataSets property without using it's name

Tags: c#, dataset

Anyone know how to reference a dataSet for example if I called it dataSet5 and don't want to use it's name.

For example if I would normally use this call to display a particular tables cell value

```
MessageBox.Show(dataSet5.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

How can I do the same as above using indexing so I can throw it in an incrementing loop similar to below which doesn't work.  I was hoping maybe it's either part of an array of form elements or components that way I can access it something like below.

```
MessageBox.Show(dataSets[24].Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Using SharpDevelop

Comment: That's a horrible idea.  You should refactor your code.

Comment: What do you mean? You lost me.

Comment: he means you shouldn't need an array of datasets, refactor you code, means get rid of duplicates and clean it up. Also as you become better at coding you notice what we call bad smells in your code, and duplicate code is just one of those bad smells.

Comment: Yeah you're right.  This started off being a quick and dirty folder delimeter modifier application for my own purposes and now with all the modifications, I am needing to do alot of cleaning.  Before I get into doing it another way. I want to see if I can traverse through the datasets in another way without having to create a new array.  For example take a look at this: for(int cc=0; cc < MyApp.MainForm.ActiveForm.Controls.Count; cc++)
   MessageBox.Show(MyApp.MainForm.ActiveForm.Controls[cc].Name); but doesn't display the datasets..

Comment: Without using the name... We need a games API... "my first is in apple, but not in orange..."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call datasets by index you have to have an array of dataset.

```
DataSet[] alldatasets = new DataSet[5];
```

Even better if you put the datasets in a List. IE.

```
List<DataSet> listDatasets = new List<DataSet>();
listDatasets.Add(new DataSet());

listDatasets[0].Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! thanks! and it does make sense.  I'm going to have to work with this a bit now. I have to figure out if I need to delete the existing datasets from my form via the GUI and recreate them in the code or passing the data to a new set.

Comment: @Michael, can I ask what you are trying to do, having multiple datasets in an array?

Comment: I got the first sample you gave working.. Wow I like that list idea too!  Just curious though if I can traverse through the datasets without having to assign them as part of a list or having to redefine them.  I figured it would be simple to reference them through a native call (if i'm explaining it right).. But thanks it's great ideas...

Comment: @Michael, if you try to reference as I did above you would get an error as there are no tables in the dataset, just an example. You would first need to fill the dataset then add it, or re-assign. IE listDatasets[0] = FillAndReturnDataSet(); or once the dataSet has been filled you can use the listDatasets.Add(myFilledDataset);

Comment: List<DataSet> listDatasets = new List<DataSet>();
listDatasets.Add(dataSet0);
MessageBox.Show(listDatasets[0].Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()); The previous code Worked and thanks for clarifying.. I still need to read up a bit.. I was hoping datasets acts like controls and not needing to create an object to put them into like another dataset array or list.. Wishful thinking on my part..

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the DataSets into your own array:

```
private DataSet[] dataSets;

...

dataSets = new DataSet[] { ... };
```

Comment: Yes thanks.. just like Jethro pointed out.. I'm going to have to work on this now...